# Can I use QueryDSL without Spring framework?

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

My Application has nothing to do with Spring(I'm using my company's own framework)
So I can use Raw JPA, but not Spring data JPA because using it will add dependency to spring with our framework. So that I cannot use Spring data JPA.
Now I'm considering adopting querydsl, but I'm not sure it will make any corelation with spring, because all of the examples on the web are using QueryDSL with Spring.
Is using querydsl does not invoke any relation with spring??